# Unable to compile PHP 5.2 with mysqli extension

Tags: php, mysqli, php-extension

I am compiling PHP version 5.2 with mysql extension mysqli

bellow are the steps

1. Configure

sudo ./configure --with-mysqli=/opt/mysql/server-5.1/bin/mysql_config

[It's working fine mysql version is 5.1 i have also try with latest]

1. make

make

[After make bellow error i am getting]

-lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lxml2 -lcrypt -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt  -o sapi/cgi/php-cgi
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_disable_reads_from_master':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:43: undefined reference to`mysql_disable_reads_from_master'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_disable_rpl_parse':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:59: undefined reference to`mysql_disable_rpl_parse'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_enable_reads_from_master':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:76: undefined reference to`mysql_enable_reads_from_master'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_enable_rpl_parse':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:93: undefined reference to`mysql_enable_rpl_parse'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_master_query':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:111: undefined reference to`mysql_master_query'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_rpl_parse_enabled':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:130: undefined reference to`mysql_rpl_parse_enabled'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_rpl_probe':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:147: undefined reference to`mysql_rpl_probe'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_rpl_query_type':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:168: undefined reference to`mysql_rpl_query_type'
ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.o: In function `zif_mysqli_slave_query':
/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.2.5/ext/mysqli/mysqli_repl.c:207: undefined reference to`mysql_slave_query'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1

Please let me know the solution

Comment: Why are you still building version 5.2? It's no longer supported. Why not upgrade to a version that is supported?

Comment: We have one old project which still running on this version

Comment: I've ran into this problem before (having to build out of date PHP versions). First make sure your building the most up-to-date version of 5.2. I'm not sure if it has recived any type of legacy support recently so you might be stuck with an old version from the archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run this command

sudo ./configure --disable-all --with-mysql=/opt/mysql/server-5.1/  --with-mysqli=/opt/mysql/server-5.1/bin/mysql_config

and it's working in my previous command i am missing the /opt/mysql/server-5.1/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your including header files from the wrong version of MySQL client. The php-mysql extension that your trying to build along with PHP 5.2 is 5+ years old and will require the library and headers from the appropriate MySQL version(s). Just doing something like 'apt-get install mysql-client mysql-client-dev' will install a recent versions, so you will likely need to download an older version and build it yourself and tell ./configure where to find the mysql headers (something like ./configure -with-mysqli=/path/to/old/headers)

edit: note that the configure flag is very important or else you will still include the wrong headers (based on your systems includes path)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default mysqlclient-dev:

```
sudo apt-get remove libmysqlclient-dev
```

Install libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.25

```
sudo wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/212189147/libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/212189159/libmysqlclient18_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient18_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I am fine!